# SQL Current month filters comparison

Tags: sql, performance, date, filter

There are 2 ways of filtering data by current month in SQL:

```
(DATEDIFF(MONTH, RecordDate, GETDATE())) = 0
```

And

```
RecordDate BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)) and EOMONTH(GetDate())
```

Are there any big differences between them?
It seems to me, that the DATEDIFF will be calculated for each row, so this should affect the performance pretty badly, but after doing some tests it seems to me that it is pretty much equivalent to the secong option.

Are there maybe some other alternatives to these 2 filters?

Comment: The first method isn't filtering.  It is just calculating a value . . . and in SQL Server would generate an error.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? All those functions are product specific.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The first method is calculating a datediff and comparing it to 0, so this could be a filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second method is going to perform better under two circumstances:

- There is an index on `RecordDate`.
- The table uses `RecordDate` for a partition key.

In a more complex query, the second version might also help the optimizer in more complex queries.

If there is no index, then the query needs to do a full table scan.  The two filtering operations are then pretty similar (as your tests show).

Or, if the table is quite small, then using an index or partitioning might not be a win.